# Java (maven) : how to know where lies the error (useless backtrace)

Tags: java, maven

I'm writing my first project with maven ([here](https://github.com/LaurentClaessens/actors)). When I run the tests with `mvn -Dtest=EchoTest test`, I get a *BUILD FAILURE* with

```
nonAcceptedTypeVerification(EchoTest)  Time elapsed: 0.044 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at EchoTest.initialize(EchoTest.java:50)
```

How can I know more precisely what line in my code triggers the `NullPointerExcepion` ?
In other words : how to ask Maven to print the whole backtrace ?

I tried `mvn -e`, and searched in the `target` subdirectory.

**EDIT**

Here are the lines provoking the NullPointerException (in EchoText.java) :

```
@Before
public void initialize() throws InterruptedException
{
    system = new EchoActorSystem();
    echo_actor = system.actorOf();  <-- line 50
}
```

The point is that `EchoActorSystem` is a quite complex class and the method `actorOf` makes tons of work, calling many functions from `system`. For example it calls `super.actorOf()` and then fix some properties of the result, and so on.
I'm searching the faulty line by adding many `Sysytem.out.println`, but I'm sure that this is not the right way to work.

Comment: Hum, isn't `at EchoTest.initialize(EchoTest.java:50)` enough? But if you want to clutter your logs, you can do `mvn -X clean test`.

Comment: Add the contents of `EchoTest.java` line 50 to your question

Comment: This almost looks like a race condition, with some other thread setting `system` to null between your two lines of code. Is this the whole `initialize()` method? Does this happen every time you run it using maven? Does it happen if run by JUnit without Maven?

Comment: @JiriTousek - In this case it is Maven eating most of the stack trace.

Comment: In fact I'm not really searching help for _this_ particular bug; massive use of println almost got me at the good place : a Map was non initialized in the constructor. What I really want is to learn using Maven better :)

Comment: @Tunaki While `-X` adds a lot of bumf to the output, maven still chops off the stack trace for test failures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mvn test -Dtest=EchoTest -DtrimStackTrace=false` will give you the complete stack trace.

The magic is `-DtrimStackTrace=false`.

Maven will default to chopping the [stacktrace](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#trimStackTrace) down to just the lines that appear in your test. Honestly this is the first time I've ever noticed this behaviour and it feels to me a very odd default (I can understand for the console output, but in the surfire-reports XML reports as well?)

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the complete stacktrace it in the `target/surfire-reports` directory, file `EchoTest.txt`

Comment: It does not. target/surefire-reports/EchoTest.txt only contains "Test run: 4 [...]   java.lang.NullPointerException at EchoTest.initialize(EchoTest.java:50)  " with no more indication on the trace  Maybe I badly set up my project ?